# QR code in which every black module or corner has rounded corners

Tags: qrcode

How would one begin to adapt this useful little package (https://ctan.org/pkg/qrcode?lang=en) to enable a call such as:

```
\qrcode[rounded corners=0.1mm]{348b0b3}%
```

Where the outcome is being able to control the corner radius of each black module from 0 to the module half-width (in which case one gets a circular modules).

Comment: In principle, I think this is possible. You can maybe patch the macro `\rule` within `\qrcode`. However, the result may not be what you expect, because the package draws each pixel independently, so connected blocks of black will appear as black dots, instead of a black rectangle with rounded corners.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PSTricks package [`pst-barcode`](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-barcode) provides an option for circular modules: **`dotty`**.

Typeset with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass[border=1bp]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\begin{document}
\makebox[1in][l]{\rule{0pt}{1in}%
  % option inkspread controls overlapping amount (in pt) of dots; <0 enlarges dots
  \psbarcode{348b0b3}{dotty inkspread=0.05 width=1 height=1}{qrcode}%
}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This technically answers your question, but the result may not be what you expected. **Option 1** (commented & result) draws a tikzpicture for each pixel, so it's slow but very flexible. **Option 2** (uncommented & not shown) scales any character to the pixel size, so it's fast but less flexible.

**MWE**

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qrcode,tikz,graphicx}
\makeatletter
\let\xqrcode@int\qrcode@int% store package macro
\def\qrcode@int{\let\xrule\rule% store old rule
  \let\rule\altrule% overwrite rule
  \xqrcode@int% package macro
  \let\rule\xrule% restore rule
}
\makeatother
% option 1: tikz (slow but flexible); tikz package
% \newcommand{\altrule}[2]{\tikzpicture% custom tikz rule
%     \fill[rounded corners=.3mm] (0,0) rectangle (#1,#2);
%   \endtikzpicture}
% option 2: any character (fast but less flexible); graphicx package
\newcommand{\altsym}{$\bullet$}% alt symbol
\newcommand{\altrule}[2]{% custom rule: logix
  \resizebox{#1}{!}{%
    \ifdim#2>0pt\altsym\else\phantom{\altsym}\fi}}
\begin{document}
\qrcode{348b0b3}
\end{document}
```

**Result**

[image: result]

Comment: The https://www.ctan.org/pkg/logix package has two squares with rounded corners. Might they help in speeding this up?

Comment: Thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz! I've edited the answer to add the generalized Option 2.

Comment: Great! I'd wish I could upvote a second time :)

Comment: Nice! Maybe you can solve [this user's problem](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/710107/distorted-qr-code-generated-using-qrcode) by making the rules a bit bigger so that they overprint horizontally and vertically?