# Distorted QR code generated using \qrcode

Tags: qrcode

When I use \qrcode, the resulting QR code image has blank lines running through it, leading to difficulty of my phone reading the QR code. Does anybody know how to remedy it? I've tried pdfLatex as well as XeLatex, and both lead to the same distorted image.
[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\begin{document}

default:\quad
\qrcode{https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/qrcode?lang=en}
\qquad
1 inch high (and wide):
\quad
\qrcode[height=1in]{https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/qrcode?lang=en}

\end{document}
```

Comment: looks ok here. Which reader did you use?

Comment: There are several duplicates around: this is a problem in the PDF viewer, I fear. this is what I have with `okular`: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XaBCZ.png

Comment: I haven't tried viewing a formal PDF of it in Adobe or Chrome....this is how it appears in the PDF viewer of MikTex

Comment: Maybe you can try to use [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/710084/38080) to add a bit of overlap to the rules... I have no time now, but I'll try to give it a shot over the week-end if nobody steps in.

Comment: The weird thing is that the white lines are not between the modules as one could expect if it was just a rounding problem with the module sizes/coordinates, but inside them (you can see a thin black line to the right of the white line when there is no black module).

Answer (score 7):

I think this is a problem with the viewer; it is shown in several questions in the site ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/692841/qr-code-contains-weird-lines), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331951/tikz-why-is-a-line-visible-between-2-fitted-nodes-with-inner-outer-sep-0/331975#331975), [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/696884/tikz-renders-filled-lines-as-dashed-with-lines)).

Probably, it could be circumvented in the package by programming a bit of overlap in the black squares (you could [check with the author](https://ctan.org/pkg/qrcode?lang=en)). Another possibility is to take charge of the PDF->pixel conversion. You can for example convert to png, blur a bit, and then resample...

```latex
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{qrcode}
\begin{document}
\qrcode{https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/qrcode?lang=en}
\end{document}
```

This as seen by Firefox (pdf.js) as:

[image]

where you can see the thin lines. You can process it with [ImageMagick](https://imagemagick.org/):

```bash
convert -density 600 -blur 0.5x1 lilla.pdf -resample 300 -sharpen 0x0.5 lilla.png
```

and then Firefox will show it as:

[image]

(You need to play with the parameters to have a better result...)

Comment: Thank you so much. The problem is that I'm having the QR code directly in a XeLaTeX document (it's a verification QR code that I want to issue on each prescription I give to patients for the pharmacies).

Comment: Rather than blurring which gives a pretty nasty result IMHO, just displaying the same QR Code twice at nearly the same position, but with a very small offset, would probably give a better result? Provided the "white" modules are actually transparent, of course.

Comment: @jcaron maybe... you can do some kind of "darken only" composition even if they are not transparent, I suppose.

Answer (score 7):

Alternatively, you can use PSTricks package [`pst-barcode`](https://ctan.org/pkg/pst-barcode). It seems to produce better results and provides a vast variety of different bar and QR code types.

Typeset with `lualatex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}

\begin{document}
default (1 inch height):\quad
\makebox[1in][l]{\rule{0pt}{1in}%
  \psbarcode{https://ctan.org/tex-archive/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-barcode}{width=1}{qrcode}%
}
\end{document}
```

Screenshot from Firefox at 400% zoom from a 1920x1080 screen:

[image]

---

Another option could be patching `qrcode`. It builds upon LaTeX's

```
\rule[raise_len]{wdth}{hght}
```

command. The visible hairlines between adjacent modules can be avoided by allowing some overlap between them, as suggested by [Rmano](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/710107/distorted-qr-code-generated-using-qrcode#comment1766312_710107).

Here, TikZ is used to re-implement the standard `\rule` with a filled `rectangle` whose border is also drawn:

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{qrcode}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\fixedrule[3][0pt]{\raisebox{#1}{\tikz[x=#2,y=#3]{
    \clip (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
    \ifdim #2>0pt\ifdim #3>0pt \filldraw (0,0) rectangle (1,1); \fi\fi
}}}
\makeatletter
\def\qrcode@in#1{\xdef\qr@texttoencode{#1}\egroup\let\rule\fixedrule\qrcode@int\endgroup}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\qrcode{ABC}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes, this seems to survive the antics of the viewers better...